# Excel Count If Function not working properly

Tags: excel-formula

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkYQN.jpg]

I am trying to use countif function in excel but it not returning the right numbers here. Some one please help me.

Comment: You need to include a lot more information here. What is the exact code? What's happening, and what are the correct outputs?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all these variants. The asterisk is a wildcard for any character, so placing it before and after the search string once will be sufficient. Countif does not do "OR" like your formula shows. You need to add the two Countif statements.

```
=COUNTIF(J:J,"*lat*")+COUNTIF(J:J,"*vit*")
```

Comment: Countif does do `OR` if you wrap it in a SUM() `=SUM(COUNTIF(J:J,{"*lat*","*vit*"}))` see: http://imgur.com/a/QvimU It is equivalent to doing the two separate ones you posted. With slightly less typing.

Comment: @ScottCraner I don't like to use whole column references in an array formula. Less typing does not mean faster calculation.

Comment: It is not an array formula, it literally is the two formulas run separate and summed, exactly like you have just combined into one.  As you can see from the picture the formula does not have the `{}` of an array entered formula.

Comment: @ScottCraner I see. You said to array enter it in the comment above. I'll run some speed tests later.

Comment: @ScottCraner I've run the different formulas through Charles Williams' FastExcel and they come up par with regards to calculation speed. So, yeah, the `Sum(countif(stuff))` works with a shorter formula. I still struggle to find a pattern where Sum() creates an envelope for a multi-cell conditional evaluation. It's far from intuitive.

Comment: @ScottCraner And I hate wrapping a formula into a SUM function, because I see so many people wrap EVERYTHING in a Sum function, like =Sum(A1+B1). In my quest to discourage that, I may be a bit overzealous. In this case, though,  I agree it's a great solution. Post it as an answer and it will get my upvote.

Comment: Sorry, realize I had put that in my comment above, I have removed the comment to avoid any confusion.  I too hate the =Sum(A1+B1) and agree it is over used.  As the formula is your formula just rewritten I see it better as a comment or amendment to your answer.  And, Thanks for verifying what I had been taught on the speed.  I learned this from Jeeped and tigeravatar.

Comment: Hi, Both these formulae count the cell twice if the cell has both letters lat and vit in them. I want the excel to count the cell only once if either one or both of them are present in the cell.

Comment: Found out a method. i think this is the only way to do it. =COUNTIFS(J:J,"*vit*",J:J,"<>*lat*")+COUNTIFS(J:J,"<>*vit*",J:J,"*lat*")+COUNTIFS(J:J,"*vit*",J:J,"*lat*"). I used the method of A-B Union B-A Union AintersectionB